# BTLE 4.0 payload

Tags: c#, c++, c, arduino, btle

I am trying to get hold of a payload that i receive from BLE which looks like this.. Am working with arduino here.

```
Got payload: 
DEC: 2 1 26 11 255 76 0 9 6 1 196 192 168 0 100 124 169 14 170 16 63 
HEX: 2 1 1A B FF 4C 0 9 6 1 C4 C0 A8 0 64 7C A9 E AA 10 3F
```

Now, im not entirely sure how to translate this. I have been reading BTLE 4.0 Spec as well but have not snapped up anything that makes sense.

Can anyone guide / point me into right direction here, would be greatly thankful!

Comment: have a look here, its about ibeacons but it explains the basics of the packet format: http://www.warski.org/blog/2014/01/how-ibeacons-work/

Answer (score 2):

BTLE 4.0 spec describes this in Volume 6, Part B, Chapter 2.

All BTLE packets follow the link layer packet format described here.
The PDU part of the BTLE packet can be one of two types: Advertising Channel PDU or Data Channel PDU.

The Advertising Channel PDU is used during advertisements (ADV_IND, SCAN_REQ, SCAN_RSP etc...). Once a connection has been established, the Data Channel PDU is used.

A description of the data format of Advertising data can be found in Volume 3, Part C, Chapter 11.